# How does a JLabel update when it is created in a different class to a Mouse Handler Object

Tags: java, swing, handler, jlabel, mouselistener

I am trying to understand the workings behind a bit of code I am playing around with.  I have the following class which is a JFrame, this simply creates a JLabel, testLabel, and adds it to the frame as well as adding a DrawPanel object to the frame.  The JLabel created is passed as an argument to DrawPanel constructor.

```
package test;

//Import statements
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class DrawFrame extends JFrame
{
    public DrawFrame()
    {
        JLabel testLabel = new JLabel("Test");
        add(new DrawPanel(testLabel),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(testLabel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

The DrawPanel class is below.  The class assigns the JLabel passed from DrawFrame to the JLabel statusLabel.  The class also registers a mouse handler to the panel and listens for a mouseMoved event and updates statusLabel with the co-ordinates of the cursor.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel 
{
    private JLabel statusLabel; 
    private JPanel labelPanel;

    public DrawPanel(JLabel statusLabel)
    {
        this.statusLabel = statusLabel;
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseHandler()); 
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter implements 
                                                    MouseMotionListener
    {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event)
        {
            statusLabel.setText(String.format("(%d, %d)", event.getX(),
                    event.getY()));
        }
    }//End inner class MouseHandler
}//End class DrawPanel
```

What I am trying to understand is how the JLabel created and added in DrawFrame is being updated when the text is set on statusLabel created in DrawPanel.

I assume it is because the JLabel passed in DrawFrame is passed by reference (as it is an object) and statusLabel in DrawPanel is referring to testLabel and so both objects are referring to the same location in memory and are not separate objects, i.e. updating the text on statusLabel also updates the text on testLabel.  Would that be correct?

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume it is because the JLabel passed in DrawFrame is passed by
>   reference (as it is an object) and statusLabel in DrawPanel is
>   referring to testLabel and so both objects are referring to the same
>   location in memory and are not separate objects, i.e. updating the
>   text on statusLabel also updates the text on testLabel. Would that be
>   correct?

More or less, yes...

Think of it this way, `testLabel` is a name to a point in memory, but only within the context where it was created (the constructor of the `DrawFrame`).

But, what you do, is pass that address to the `DrawPane` and you give it the name `statusLabel`, both `testLabel` and `statusLabel` now refer to the same place in memory (or the object at that memory location).

I could confuse you more and let you know that all object variables in Java are pointers, but unlike C/C++, you simply can manipulate the pointer (only the content it points to) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification MadProgrammer that helps the concept sit better in my brain :) much appreciated